# Accessing objects in an array based on corresponding object in another array

Tags: c#, arrays

I've recently started coding and I'm trying to make minesweeper with windows forms.
I have an array, like so:

```
tiles = new PictureBox[30,16];
```

I also have another array, like this:

```
mines = new int[30,16];
```

The code for generating the grid of pictureboxes and randomizing the mines works.

I randomize where to put the mines in a separate method and store the locations in the mines array. Now I want a way to access the element in the mines array that corresponds to the index in the picturebox array so that I can calculate what is in that tile.

Anyone have any ideas if this is possible? I have considered using the picturebox.name property to track whether or not there is a mine in a certain tile, but I'm unsure of what effect the name property has. I could probably do it by calculating the coordinates of the mouseclick but I would really like to avoid that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me that you would be able to figure out the picture based on the content of the mines array. Why do you need two arrays?

Comment: When i click one of the pictureboxes the eventhandler gives me which box it should work with, i need a way to track whats under each box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Tag` for storing data that you need, for example you can save a `Tuple<int,int>` in `Tag` so when a picture box is clicked you can retreive it via `((sender as PictureBox).Tag as Tuple<int,int>)` in `OnClick` event handler, then you know this picture box is in which row and in which column, 
Do not forget to assign `Tag` when you are populating your `tiles` array